# Deserializar Imagem em ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, webforms, asp

Bem estou com uma dúvida a respeito da deserialização de uma imagem em webforms, estou trabalhando com Banco de dados Oracle que é meu context e usando o entity framework para imagem estou utilizando BLOB, consegui serializar e da commit no bd, mas não consigo deserializar.
Codigo:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int t = 0; //Variavel de teste - BreakPoint
    ProjetoContext bd = new ProjetoContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if(!IsPostBack)
    //    {
    //        this.CarregarGrind();
    //    }

    }

    //Inserindo imagem 
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUp.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUp.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = FileUp.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                IMG_PRODUTO img = new IMG_PRODUTO();
                img.IMAGEM = bytes;
                img.DESCRICAO = "computador";
                img.PRODUTOes = null;

                bd.IMG_PRODUTO.Add(img);

                bd.SaveChanges();

               // bd.IMG_PRODUTO(img);
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }


    //private void CarregarGrind() //Entra no metodo mas não realiza o build
    //{
    //        var img = bd.IMG_PRODUTO.ToList();

    //        gvImages.DataSource = img.ToString();
    //        gvImages.DataBind();
    //}

  /*  protected void gvImages_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //Nem entra nesse if ele já pula fora, mesmo com blob salvo no BD
        {
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)["IMAGEM"];
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            (e.Row.FindControl("Imagem1") as Image).ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
        }
        e.Row.
        byte[] byteDaImagem;


    }/*
}
```

Comment: Mas, não consigo deserializar em qual local? como deseja fazer isso.

Comment: Bem, como disse a cima, tenho a imagem salva no BD em Blob, no evento RowDataBound era pra deserializar a imagem, gostaria de usar tecnicas do Entity que a view fosse no grid

Comment: Tem alguns formas de fazer isso, uma delas é com um pagina que só executa código talvez seja a melhor solução.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de código? ou site pois estou debugando e nunca entra no meu if. if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //Nem entra nesse if ele já pula fora, mesmo com blob salvo no BD

Comment: Deixa eu procurar como seria melhor pra você

Comment: ok, vou ficar no aguardo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69226/discussion-between-antonio-sistema-de-informacao-and-virgilio-novic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou propor um exemplo mediante um modelo exemplo, porque, no seu modelo atual falta alguns campos referente ao `ContentType` e tamanho físico do arquivo para mostrar a imagem corretamente vindo do banco de dados, exemplo minimo:

Modelo e Tabela utilizados com Entity Framework (nada impede ser feito por qualquer ORM ou Micro ou até puramente com o Framework .NET tem):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

após isso a pagina que contem um componente `GridView`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ImageField
                      DataImageUrlField="Id" 
                      DataImageUrlFormatString="Load.ashx?Id={0}">
                    </asp:ImageField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>            
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

nesse exemplo de página `ASPX` tem o GridView e uma coluna `ImageField` com dois parâmetros importantes:

- `DataImageUrlField="Id"`

esse configuração especifica a identificação da imagem na base de dados, comumente chamado de chave primária.

- `DataImageUrlFormatString="Load.ashx?Id={0}"`

e essa configuração é para chamar um outro arquivo com a extensão `ashx` (`Generic Handler`) que tem a função de executar somente código ou página careca como é chamado por alguns desenvolvedores.

Nessa página tem o código responsável para gerar a sua imagem:

```
using System.Web;
using WebApplication15.Models;

namespace WebApplication15
{

    public class Load : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString(), out var id))
            {
                using (BaseDadosEntities db = new BaseDadosEntities())
                {
                    Imagens img = db.Imagens.Find(id);
                    if (img != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = img.ContentType;
                        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(img.Picture, 0, (int)img.Size);
                    }
                }
            }
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

visto que no seu modelo atual não tem `ContentType` e `Size` que é o tamanho da imagem fica difícil saber o tipo e gerar a imagem com o tamanho correto são itens que precisam existir na sua tabela.

***Observação de código:***

Para gravar a imagem com array de bytes em sua base de dados não precisa daquele código, o próprio componente `FileUpload` te fornece os dados necessários para gravar a imagem, exemplo:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    using (BaseDadosEntities db = new BaseDadosEntities())
    {
        Imagens img = new Imagens();
        img.ContentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        img.Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        img.Size = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        img.Picture = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        db.Imagens.Add(img);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Call_Grid(db);
    }
}
```

código ideal e sem utilizar outros meios que no meu ver são totalmente desnecessários para o caso especifico.

---

***Outra forma*** seria com Evento [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) com um [TemplateField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) da seguinte forma, na `GridView` coloque um `layout` assim:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:TemplateField>                        
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100" Height="100" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

e no método `GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` escreve o código:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text, out var id))
        {                    
            Imagens im = db.Imagens.Find(id);
            if (im != null)
            {
                Image img = (Image)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("Image1");
                img.ImageUrl = 
                    $"data:{im.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(im.Picture)}";
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Código completo:*

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected BaseDadosEntities db;
    protected void Call_Grid()
    {            
        GridView1.DataSource = db.Imagens.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        db.Dispose();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (db == null) db = new BaseDadosEntities();
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            Call_Grid();
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (db != null) db.Dispose();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text, out var id))
            {                    
                Imagens im = db.Imagens.Find(id);
                if (im != null)
                {
                 Image img = (Image)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("Image1");
                 img.ImageUrl = 
                  $"data:{im.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(im.Picture)}";
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Evento GridView.RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Propriedade TemplateField.ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Opa, era isso mesmo ! Ajudou bastante